# Prove $\phi=0$ if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}x^{\alpha}\phi=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

These are two closely related question to prove

1)If $\phi\in C_0^{\infty}$,and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}x^{\alpha}\phi=0$ for all multiindices $\alpha$, 
where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n),x^{\alpha}=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$
then $\phi=0$

2)There exists $\phi$ in Schwartz class s.t. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}x^{\alpha}\phi=0$.

---

It is quite confusing because $C_{0}^{\infty}$ is dense in Schwartz class and I don't know how to prove these two statements.

Comment: 1) Fix a compact $K$ containing the support of $\phi$ and note that polynomials are dense in $C(K)$  hence you can uniformly approximate $\overline \phi$. Taking linear combinations and limits yield $\int_K |\phi|^2 =0$ and hence $\phi=0$. Concerning 2) you probably want some non-zero $\phi\in\mathscr S$. An idea would be to prove the surjectivity of $T:\mathscr S(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb C^{\mathbb N_0}$, $\phi\mapsto \left(\int x^k\phi(x)\right)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ using Eidelheit's theorem and to note that $T$ cannot be an isomorphism because $\mathscr S$ has continuous norms.

Comment: @Jochen: Maybe easier: Take $\phi \in S $ with $\widehat {\phi} \in C_c^\infty  (\Bbb {R}^n \setminus \{ 0\}) $ and note $\int x^\alpha \phi = c_\alpha \partial^\alpha \hat {\phi}(0) =0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: You're right. That's much easier.